# How to return an array from a function in php

Tags: php, arrays, function

With the following code I have two problems with the code:

First I'm calling in an array into a function:

```
  function dateUpdate($key) {
     return $key;
  }
```

Then I used the following print statement to check my work:

```
      echo ("<pre>");
             print_r($key);
      echo ("</pre>");
```

The issue that seems to be happening is when I'm trying to return the array, first I tried it with a global call $key and I get nothing, however, when I remove global call, I get an error stating the variable $key is undefined. Is there a way for the array that is called in to the function and sent out via the return statement.

Thank you...

Comment: Try print_r (dateUpdate($key)):

Comment: Let's start with showing us your **full** and **real** code

Comment: Well I tried it an nothing was returning....

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it happened to be the location of the function that was causing the issue.